# Angular 2/4: Add compiled component to an iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

I have a new Angular app (can use v 2.4.10 or 4.0.0-rc.5), which uses an iframe to embed some pre-existing content. Using a method called when the iframe loads -- `(load)="processIframe(extFrame)"` -- I'm able to set up listeners via the Angular Renderer, and to grab references to child DOM elements ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38457886/2924969) helped with that process).

It's easy enough to set the content of an element in the iframe by replacing its `innerHtml`. However, what I need to do is the replace this html with a compiled Angular component. This component grabs some data from an API via a service.

Is there a way to replace DOM element content in the iframe with the compiled component?

Comment: Since you have `ElementRef` you can try [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html)

Comment: Great question, i'm doing something similar and would love to know if this is possible.

Comment: do you need a solution for Angular 2.4.10 or 4.0.0-rc.5 only? Are you ok with a newer version, like 4.1.3?

Comment: I don't see how you could add a component you created on your document to another document (iframe) directly. Are you ok with an alternative solution, for example, loading a separate route in your iframe and communicate between the main document and iframe document the intent of loading a component with some specific data, and any changes that may appear? Don't see any other way.

Comment: @andreim if you make the `src` in the iframe another route, does it load the app twice?

Comment: @paqogomez yes it does. Another DOM another app instance. But if the app is not loading all resources ahead and it uses async loading (see routing loadChildren property) then is fine.

Comment: @andreim I've opted instead to put my code in a guard on the route, this seems to work well for what I'm doing, but is different that OP.  If you want to make an answer as best you can, i'll give you the bounty.

Comment: @fiona, for your situation, why not just make a component that loads the data and forego the iframe altogether?

Comment: @fiona doing `<my-component>Some random content for iframe</my-component>` and then in template `<iframe><ng-content></ng-content></iframe>` will not work because the `<iframe>` constructs a separate DOM and anything inside the `<iframe>` will go away. Also cannot obtain a `ViewContainerRef` from the `<iframe>` body element in order to pass the template to that one, as far as I know, because you cannot query the element which actually does not exist, is created at runtime dynamically.

Answer (score 16):

You can create `ComponentRef` instance and then insert its `compRef.location.nativeElement` in desired place.

I would do it as follows **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/xYMcAkzc5CCjpMQlXFtC?p=preview)**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="createComponent()">Create component</button>
    <iframe #iframe (load)="onLoad()"></iframe>
  `,
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

  doc: any;
  compRef: ComponentRef<DynamicComponent>;

  constructor(
    private vcRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}


  createComponent() {
    const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
    this.compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory);

    this.doc.body.appendChild(this.compRef.location.nativeElement);
  }

  onLoad() {
    this.doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || 
               this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.onLoad(); // in Firefox state is uninitialized while 
                   // in Chrome is complete so i use `load` event for Firefox
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.compRef) {
      this.compRef.destroy();
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add `DynamicComponent` to `entryComponents array