# how to set localhost path on iframe in angular 4

Tags: angular, iframe, angular4-forms, angular4-router, angular4-httpclient

Hi please help to solve the code.
if I embed static HTML file that is stored in my project directory the iframe is not working when i embed live URL in the iframe the iframe is working fine

here my folder structure

```
src
|-app
|  |-components
|      |-template
|            |-template.component.html
|            |-template.component.ts
|-assets
|-templates
     |-template1
          |-index.html
```

**template.component.html**

```
<iframe [src]="getIframe()" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

**template.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template',
  templateUrl: './template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template.component.css']
})

export class TemplateComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getIframe(){
    console.log('iframe');
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('../../../templates/template1/index.html');
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you double-triple checked the location? Maybe try to put a temp file into the same folder?

Comment: Add templates folder to .angular file? Access the folder from root directory not using .../..; recommended is making use of assets folder

Comment: Yes I Put the html file in assets folder but it's not working

Comment: Yes i checked the location multiple times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2/4: Add compiled component to an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875013/angular-2-4-add-compiled-component-to-an-iframe)

Answer (score 2):

Make a file in root directory which saves an alias to filepath mappings, then call the function from that file by passing alias which will give you the path of the required file.
Example:

```
    'use strict';
define([    
], function(){

    var baseUrl = '/dashboard/app'; // the url starting with this file

    var html = {
        'file1'     : 'file_1.html',
        'file2'     : 'app2/file_2.html'
    };

    function getHtml(alias) {
        if(html[alias]) {
            return baseUrl + html[alias];
        }
    };

    return {
        getHtml : getHtml
    }; });
```

Now require this file and call the getHtml function with the required file path , this gives you the accurate file path from home directory.

This should most probably work, try and let me know.