# iframe not loading styles using srcdoc attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, iframe

I am using an `iframe` in an Angular component, and while using the `src` attribute to load a site loads, the styles and content perfectly fine. When trying to load static html in as a string with the `srcdoc` attribute, only the HTML appears to be rendering. The following is a very basic example that I've reduced this to that still isn't loading the styles.

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-newsletter-viewer',
  templateUrl: './newsletter-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./newsletter-viewer.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class NewsletterViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  newsletterSrcDoc: string;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newsletterSrcDoc = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" />
    <style>
    p {
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
    }
    </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="page">
        <div id="template2">
        <div class="section-cover-photo">
        <div class="col">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="" class="cover-photo">
        <div class="banner-template2">
          <h1>Test Title</h1>
          <p>This is a test document.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
    `;
  }

}
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 170px;
  height: 220px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.frame {
  width: 8.5in;
  height: 11in;
  border: 0;
  -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
  -o-transform: scale(0.25);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
  transform: scale(0.25);
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <iframe class="frame" [srcdoc]="newsletterSrcDoc"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

After taking a different approach in searching for related topics on Stack Overflow, the accepted answer on this topic seemed to work for me: [iframe inside angular2 component, Property 'contentWindow' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457662/iframe-inside-angular2-component-property-contentwindow-does-not-exist-on-typ)

From what I can tell, the issue has to do with how/when Angular chooses to render the DOM in the iframe. If the iframe's document content is rendered after the View (specifically the `iframe` in the View) is initialized, then the iframe's `<head>` tag is no longer omitted from the complete DOM structure on the web page.